# 5GHz WLAN connection on acer S7

Tags: wireless, acer, ultrabook

during the last days I installed Kubuntu on my new Acer S7 Ultrabook.
After some trouble with the the boot configuration this now works fine so that Kubuntu runs in parallel with Windows 8 on my machine.
Only one problem I discovered at the moment.
With my Acer S7 under Kubuntu it is not possible to connect to my 5Ghz WLAN.
The machine sees the WLAN, but when I try to connect it just tells me for several minutes "getting IP-Address" and then it stops with "can't connect".
The 2.4GHz WLAN works fine on the machine and also on other machines running Linux (my wifes Samsung Series 5, two old Dell Notebooks) the 5GHz WLAN works fine.
Just my new Acer S7 is not able to connect.

Does anyone know, how to make this machine also connect to my 5GHz WLAN?

Within this questions I just found some hints, to disable the n-option to restrict the driver to 54MBit. But on ma machine this doesn't help, and the other machines run also without this disabling without any problems.
So it seems to be a specific problem of this machine and not that 5GHz WLAN would not work properly under Ubuntu/Linux.

Bye

Ralf

Answer (score 2):

today I just found out, how to get the 5 GHz network to work.
I installed the compat-wireless drivers (package linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-21-generic) on my system and now also this network works without problems.

May be, this hint also helps someone, having similar problems.

Just to add, the chipset on my Acer Aspire S7 is an Atheros Communications Inc. AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01), just in case, this problems occurs also on other systems with the same chipset.

Bye

Ralf

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. This helped me on an Acer Aspire V5-171 with the same Atheros AR9462 chipset, running Quantal Quetzal (12.10), with similar problems (2.4GHz OK, but cannot connect @ 5Ghz).

For those less familiar with installation, here are some tips.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-headers-quantal-generic
```

This pulled in the right versions for my kernel (and should continue to do so when I updated my kernel in the future). I don't believe the headers were needed; I installed them just in case ...

I also avoided a reboot by disabling wireless, then removing and re-installing the ath9k module:

```
modprobe -r ath9k
modprobe ath9k
```

then re-enabling wireless in Network Manager and connecting.